# Convert geo location to x y coordinates to get relative postion from a center point?

Tags: python, plot, geolocation, trigonometry

I am trying to capture relative position from one Lat Long coordinate in the center to all the other coordinates.

To give you an example, let’s say we have 3 cities Amsterdam, London and Zurich.

Amsterdam is supposed to be my center point with (0,0) xy coordinates on a 2D plane. Now with compass bearing I am trying to calculate the relative direction of both London (west) and Zurich (south-east) from Amsterdam. Once I have the direction captured and distance also calculated between Amsterdam and London as well as Amsterdam and Zurich, I want to plot this as XY coordinates.

I am not sure what I am missing in this. Am I conceptually wrong?

Current Output:

[image: Current Output:]

Expected Output:

[image: Expected Output:]

Code Sample:

```
import math

def calc_compass_bearing(pointA, pointB):

    lat1 = math.radians(pointA[0])
    lat2 = math.radians(pointB[0])

    diffLong = math.radians(pointB[1] - pointA[1])

    x = math.sin(diffLong) * math.cos(lat2)
    y = math.cos(lat1) * math.sin(lat2) - (math.sin(lat1)
                                           * math.cos(lat2) * math.cos(diffLong))

    initial_bearing = math.atan2(x, y)

    initial_bearing = math.degrees(initial_bearing)
    compass_bearing = (initial_bearing + 360) % 360

    return compass_bearing


def calc_dist(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2):

    R = 6372.8  # earth radius in kms

    dLat = math.radians(lat2 - lat1)
    dLon = math.radians(lon2 - lon1)
    lat1 = math.radians(lat1)
    lat2 = math.radians(lat2)

    a = math.sin(dLat / 2)**2 + math.cos(lat1) * \
        math.cos(lat2) * math.sin(dLon / 2)**2
    c = 2 * math.asin(math.sqrt(a))

    return R * c


locs = {'london': (51.509865, -0.118092),
        'zurich': (47.36667, 8.55),
        'amsterdam': (52.377956, 4.897070)}


# center point here is amsterdam
cp = 'amsterdam'
cp_geo_cords = locs[cp]
cp_xy_cords = (0, 0)


plot_input = {}
for i in locs.keys():
    rp_geo_cords = locs[i]

    if i == cp:
        plot_input[i] = cp_xy_cords
    else:
        bearing = calc_compass_bearing(cp_geo_cords, rp_geo_cords)
        dist = calc_dist(
            cp_geo_cords[0], cp_geo_cords[1], rp_geo_cords[0], rp_geo_cords[1])

        bearing_rad = bearing * (math.pi / 180)  # convert bearing to radians
        delta_x = dist * math.sin(bearing_rad)
        delta_y = dist * math.cos(bearing_rad)
        tree_x = cp_xy_cords[0] + delta_x
        tree_y = cp_xy_cords[1] + delta_y

        plot_input[i] = (tree_x, tree_y)


#plotting using pyvis
from pyvis.network import Network
net = Network(height='800px', width='1200px')

for node in plot_input.keys():
    net.add_node(node, color='red', size=15,
                 x=plot_input[node][0], y=plot_input[node][0], physics=False)

net.show("output.html")
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the error. While plotting I was using x cordniate in y parameter as well.

```
for node in plot_input.keys():
    net.add_node(node, color='red', size=15,
                 x=plot_input[node][0], y=plot_input[node][0], physics=False)
```

Code works perfectly after fixing this! Just have to invert the Y-axis.